# What is the fastest/ best way to convert between two classes or Structs with the exact same layout in .Net?

Tags: .net, type-conversion

If this is a duplicate I'm sorry, I searched for it but couldn't find it.

I'm currently writing a voxel based 3D game using MonoGame and BEPUphysics. The problem is that in order to not be dependent on XNA or MonoGame, BEPUphysics created it's own Vector2, Vector3, and Matrix classes. BEPUphysics provides a MathConverter class with a heavily overloaded Convert function for converting between it's classes and the structurally identical XNA classes.  All each function does is create a new instance of the desired type and right to left all of the properties.  This is a very straightforward method of doing it but it feels like there should be other ways since the block of memory each class uses should be the same size and layout as well. So are there other ways to achieve the same result? What are the pros and cons of these ways primarily with respect to speed but also just in general? Or is a naive right to left implementation the only or best way? Even though both projects are open source and I technically could modify them to be the same type or at least have a same base type
, I'd rather not do that and the question still stands for a situation where one or both of the classes is in a compiled closed source assembly.

Comment: If you absolutely knew that they were completely identical internally you could simply typecast them.  However, since we are talking about classes rather than a set of `struct` types, this is very unlikely to be true.  Hence, the conversion member functions.

Comment: They are completely identical, or so I thought... but trying to set a = (aType)b; said could noy convert, so I guess RTL or automapper are my only choices.. thanks.